# Cannot resolve symbol 'mail'

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to send an email using my application made in Android Studio, but something is wrong. Android Studio says that the symbols cannot be resolved, so nothing won't work. Are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Have you imported the javax.mail library into your project?

Comment: I downloaded a JAR-file called javax.mail-1.3.3.01, but I don't know where to put it. I tried to put it into the lib folder, but nothing happend.

Comment: Did you add your  javax.mail library to the dependencies ?

Comment: Right click on it and select "Add as library"

Comment: @NickIsaacs I think so .

Comment: I have not changed anything in the dependencies, should I do that aswell?

Comment: once you add as library your build.gradle should have 'compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')'

Comment: Where to right click, @NickIsaacs?

Comment: @thehulk after copying to the lib folder, right click on the jar and select 'Add as library'

Comment: NickIsaacs solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Make it as library Source**

> Copy Required .jar file as per version from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/mail.htm)
>
> Then copy it and paste it into libs(recommended) folder or any where you want in project directory. Lastly right click on the .jar (which is you pasted) file and select Add As Library.

Answer (score 0):

Put your library in the lib folder and in your root dependency add the line

> compile files('libs/your library name')

and then sync your gradle 
Try this